# How to update data on React frontend that are yielded in Flask backend by generator?

Tags: reactjs, flask

When a client hits one of my Flask endpoints, I want to construct a python generator that yields a new image every ~5 seconds and sends the image to the React frontend to be updated.

What is the right way to do this? How can I have React update the displayed image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered creating a WebSocket connection between the frontend and backend? The socket can remain open and the server can be configured to send the new image in a time interval. On the frontend, you can store the image URL using `React.useState` and update it in a function that listens for new messages from the WebSocket.

These may be helpful:

https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/

Comment: I'm currently investigating Server Side Events (SSE). Why do you recommend a WebSocket over SSE?

Comment: Since you won't be sending data from the client to the server, SSE does seem like a better option. This may help with the frontend: https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-a-build-real-time-react-app-with-server-sent-events-9fbb83374f90